# WinRAR installation on Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10

How can I install WinRAR on my Ubuntu 10.04 system? I tried `sudo apt-get install rar`.

Answer (score 12):

WinRAR is a windows program for using RAR type files.  There is no 'WinRAR' on Ubuntu.

Installing `rar` like you did should add support for RAR files into the standard "archive manager" for ZIPS, TARs, etc.

(copied from William Fleming, he got some of my upvote power for his answer)
Installing `unrar` will help you with unpacking them:  `sudo apt-get install unrar`

Comment: gave you my up vote power ha!

Comment: It seems that `rar` can also unpack `.rar` files. So, what is the point of installing `unrar`?

Comment: @HoseinRahnama I haven't audited the `rar` command, however most tooling requires `unrar` to unpack the RAR file.  Note this answer was written in 2012, so things might've changed since then.

Comment: Yeah, that's an old answer. It would be nice if you update this answer by including some explanation about `rar` too. It seems that `rar` can compress and decompress while `unrar` only decompresses.

Comment: @HoseinRahnama When time permits it I can.  I'm quite busy nowadays though so sometimes I don't get to update the older answers I've written.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

This will allow you to unpack them.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to install WinRAR in Ubuntu:

#### Method 1: Install the available `rar` and `unrar` tools

In the Terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rar unrar
sudo apt-get clean
```

It will install the `rar` software and after installation, it will open `rar` files in the archive manager

#### Method 2: Install `wine` and then WinRAR

Install `wine` and download the winrar.exe from WinRAR website and install the WinRAR software similar steps to be followed for the installation in windows and after that rar files are able to open

For more details see [this blog post](http://dcageek.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-install-winrar-on.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to [this](http://www.rarlab.com/shop2rarlab.php?prod=linux), it's a commercial version, as you can see, and it has not a GUI.

I suggest using file-roller, which is the default archive manager for the GNOME desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the pre-installed Archive Manager can open some compressed files, but during my experience to open some `.rar` format, that brought me an error. one of the practical app to open such files and extract them is `unrar` that can be installed through the command below:

> sudo apt-get install unrar

for this purpose, the useful command and its functionality is here:

- test your `rar` file if it is corrupted :`unrar t <yourRARFile>`
- extract the containing file in full path: `unrar x <yourRARFile>`